# java Mac OS Sierra

Tags: mac, sierra

Столкнулся с информацией, что при установке java на Mac os Sierra 
10.13.1 (17B48) JVM вызывает исключения NullPointerException в 
MacOS Sierra 10.12 .

Как решается эта проблема?(Недавно приобрел Mac, поэтому и возник такой глупый вопрос.)

Comment: Вот прямо таки инсталлятор выбрасывает исключение?

Comment: Нет. Я еще не ставил, чтобы избежать лишних проблем, решил тут поинтересоваться. Потому что эта инфа написана на офф сайте java

Comment: Тогда наверняка там же содержится и решение вопроса